# Enum having range of integers

Tags: c++, enums

I want doorPosition_DEG to have a value between 1-90 (degrees). Is it possible to do this? Is it convenient?

```
enum doorPosition_DEG {0,1,2,3,4... 90 };
```

seems like `enum doorPosition_DEG { 0-90 };` is invalid

Comment: you have to give a name to each position

Comment: I would rather just use an `int doorPosition_DEG` and check for illegal values where needed.

Comment: just checking if it is possible, now seen its disabilities

Comment: how are you going to use a specific position from enum doorPosition_DEG if it has no name?

Comment: C++ doesn't have range-restricted integers like that built-in. You could create your own class or import one, but there would be run-time penalty from all the checking.

Comment: Even if you define an `enum` type with values from 0 to 90, you can still legally assign 100 to an object of the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that. You have to give each one its own name. You have a couple of options:

You could give each one its own name.

You could just use an `int`, and validate that it is in [0, 90] when necessary:

```
int doorPosition = 32; // e.g. when storing

// or when using (use whatever error handling you'd like)
void setDoorPosition (int pos) {
   if (pos < 0 || pos > 90)
      throw runtime_error("Door position must be from 0 to 90.");
}
```

The above could use a typedef if you'd rather be clear about it (you would still have to check the range explicitly, of course):

```
typedef int DoorPosition;
```

You could also define a small custom class to use to represent positions, with `0 <= position <= 90` as an invariant, e.g.:

```
class DoorPosition {

private:

  int position;

public: 

  explicit DoorPosition (int p) {
     setPosition(p);
  }

  void setPosition (int p) {
     if (p < 0 || p > 90)
        throw runtime_error("Door position must be from 0 to 90.");
     // ^ or optionally clamp to valid range, if that's more appropriate
     position = p;
  }

  int getPosition () const {
     return position;
  }

};
```

Override various useful operators as necessary.

Comment: @lizusek What the heck. I totally tripped out there. One minute.